# C# State changes in SQL-To-Entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm working with **SQL-To-Entity**, and I've been wondering which changes you can "re-use" immediately after changing entries, for example

1) Lookup record, change a member and use `Database.Entry(Entry).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Now, can I use the changes I made to this entry immediately after? If i do another lookup does the entry reflect that I changed that member or do I need to do `SaveChanges()`?

Also, what about Insert/Delete? If I insert a record and mark it as inserted as above, does it appear in a select statement using that same context before `SaveChanges()`?

Thanks in advance!